# REGEX - Find all values, after specific parameter and until new text started

Tags: python, regex

Sample text =  "deductions amount XXX 123.45 555.55 YYY 22.00"

I need to find values after a specific parameter. For example if I will use `XXX (\d+[.,]\d+)` I will find `123.45`.

Question , what regex will need to be used to find ALL values after a specific parameter and NOT using something like this: `XXX (\d+[.,]\d+) (\d+[.,]\d+) (\d+[.,]\d+) and e.t.c..` So I need ALL value AFTER the specific parameter UP to the next text.

By using the sample text I would like to return:

- XXX = ["123.45","555.5"]
- YYY = ["22.00"]

Comment: You could use `XXX ((([\d.]+) ?)+)` and then use `.split()` on your first captured group to get a list of all values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
import re

sample = 'deductions amount XXX 123.45 555.55 YYY 22.00'

for match in re.findall(r'([A-Z]{3}) ((?:\d*(?:\.\d+)\s?)+)', sample):
    print(f'{match[0]} = {match[1].split()}')
```

Result:

```
XXX = ['123.45', '555.55']
YYY = ['22.00']
```

Comment: That question was closed due to there being not enough details. The main problem is likely that you provided no code at all. You can try asking a new question about that problem, just be sure to include your best attempt and explain where you're stuck, or what is surprising about the output you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [OR operator](https://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/or-in-regex/), and the `findall` function.

```
import re

sample_text = 'deductions amount XXX 123.45 555.55 YYY 22.00'

for item in re.findall(r'(XXX|YYY) ((?:\d*(?:\.\d+)\s?)+)', sample_text):
    print(item[0] +' =', item[1].split())
```

Result:

[image]